# PHP selector in jquery having issue of unexpected token in console

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento, magento2

I have used below script sometimes it's work but sometimes it's gives error in console that is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < on first line.

```
 $(<?php echo  '"#'.$itemid.'"'; ?>).click(function() {

            $("#options").modal(options).modal('openModal');

        });
```

Even in inspect element in html the result is showing

```
   $("#2735").click(function() {

            $("#options").modal(options).modal('openModal');

        });
```

Not getting what is the issue here..i used this script [Script is here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/109151)

Comment: Is this code called in a loop ? If so, let us see the loop's code as well.

Comment: My be `$itemid` not return value coz make error try to change it to `@$itemid` and see if return value or be empty

Comment: You could change your code to:  $("#<?php echo $itemid?>") and see what happens.

Comment: @SamirNabil i chnaged it..but now modal is working

Comment: @jeff It gives error Invalid selector string (XSS) in console

Comment: @SagarKodte try to give him an empty itemid and see if still give you that error and try it again without @ to see if that error came if the itemid are null

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what's happen but in a simple way you can write

```
$("#<?php echo  $itemid; ?>")
```

is what itemid is always an integer ?

maybe is more secure

```
$("#<?php echo  intval($itemid); ?>")
```

maybe in some case $itemid is null or empty and the client code will be

```
$("#")
```

or maybe an invisible char like \n ?

but i don't think your problem is located here

["Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < " in first line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39230493/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-first-line)